# SSIS 2008 shared data source for attunity

Tags: oracle, ssis, connectivity, attunity

I am using Attunity (V 1.2) connection for Oracle in my SSIS 2008. Our Oracle DBAs are often changing the passwords and I have to change all my SSIS connections one by one accordingly. Is there a way to change all attunity connections? (Specially the password)

Comment: Are you asking how to [parameterize connection strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451758/how-to-parameterize-database-connection-string-in-an-ssis-package)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS how to set connection string dynamically from a config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497875/ssis-how-to-set-connection-string-dynamically-from-a-config-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by adding a package configuration.